# SqlException in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlexception

I have a function that calls a stored procedure. But it throws an exception some thing like this :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Invalid column name 'quantity'.
>
> Invalid column name 'quantity'.
>   Invalid column name 'location'.
>   Invalid column name 'quantity'.
>   Invalid column name 'quantity'.
>   Invalid column name 'quantity'. ...

I don't understand why this exception is thrown because the stored procedure works fine in MSSMS.

Here is my code for calling the stored procedure:

```
public DataSet getDataTable_sp(string sp_name, SqlParameter[] p = null)
{
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connstr))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sp_name,conn);
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 300;

                if (p != null)
                    for (int i = 0; i < p.Count(); i++)
                        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(p[i].ParameterName, p[i].SqlDbType, p[i].Size).Value = p[i].Value;

                conn.Open();
                da.Fill(ds); // this is the line that the exception is thrown
                conn.Close();
            }

            return ds;
}
```

Comment: I think the exception is clear: `Invalid column name 'quantity'` means, there is no column named 'quantity'. You might connect to the wrong database or you'll need to create the tables first.

Comment: Check whether the connection is appropriate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have also encountered the same error before, I think the problem was on your stored procedure. Try to check all the declarations, specially your temporary tables. I don't know if it will works on your part. Try to avoid the same temporary tables name. Just try it :)

Comment: yes you are right. I have same temporary table names in my stored procedures

Comment: Ahh i see. I'm glad i was able to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Check columns names, columns in stored procedure must be the same as attributes declared in  your Model.